# Appending Params PUT Request - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I am using HttpParams with a put request but I keep getting a bad request. I am not sure what I am doing wrong:

**.TS**

```
this.dataService.publishData('1234', 'myVar')
       .subscribe(() => console.log('success'),
        () => console.log('error')
)
```

**SERVICE.TS**

```
public publishData(list: string, type: string){
   var url = '*****/****/***';'
   let urlParams = new HttpParams();
   urlParams = urlParams.append(type, list);

   return this.http.put(url, {params:urlParams});
}
```

> Result: Error 400:  Required List parameter &#39

**Expected result:**

```
http.myurl/?myVar=1234
status: 200
```

Comment: You don't seem to include those params when you make the request. Also you seem to be sending a PUT without a body (i.e. without an *"enclosed entity"*).

Comment: @jonsharpe I updated the body. what do you mean I don't seem to include those params

Comment: Well before that edit `urlParams` was defined but not used in the `http.put` call. Now it *is*, but as the body of the request rather than in the options where it's supposed to be (assuming you do want that added as a URL query parameter). Did you read the [definition of `put`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#put)?

Comment: Yeah I tried to but I don't really understand the docs. The options?

Comment: That's not really a clear enough question. You can also read the guide, which includes [an example of a PUT](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-put-request).

Comment: I just updated my question with a little more detail. Ill checkout that article

Comment: If you want the query parameters in the URL, not as the body of the request, they need to be in the options object. That's the *third* parameter, because [PUT requests](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) expect a *body*.

Comment: oh ok so something like `(url, null, {params:urlParams)`

Comment: Just curious, you have the _expected result_ outlined above but what is the ***actual result*** that you're seeing if you log the generated url?

Comment: @War10ck I was getting a: 400 badrequest `Error 400: Required List parameter `&#39